# find duplicated record by first and last name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `beneficials`. Some facts about it:

- A beneficial belongs to `one` organization
- An organization has `many` beneficial
- Beneficials have first and last names and no other identification form.

Some sample data from the table

```
| id | firstname | lastname | organization_id |
|----|-----------|----------|-----------------|
| 1  | jan       | kowalski | 1               |
| 2  | jan       | kovalski | 3               |
| 3  | john      | doe      | 1               |
| 4  | jan       | kowalski | 2               |
```

I want to find if a `beneficial` from an organization is also present in other organizations through first and last name and if so, I want to get the organization or organizations ids.

in the sample data above, what I want is given organization id `1`, the query should return `2` because `jan kowalski` is also beneficial on organization `2` but not `3` because even though they match the first name, they don't match the last name

I came up with the following query:

```sql
with org_beneficials as (
  select firstname, lastname from beneficials where organization_id = ? and deleted_at is null
)
select organization_id from beneficials 
    where firstname in (select firstname from org_beneficials)
    and lastname in (select lastname from org_beneficials)
    and deleted_at is null
    and organization_id <> ?;
```

it *kinda* works but returns some false positive if beneficial from different organizations share the same first or last name. I need to match both first and last names and I can't figure out how.

I thought about joining the table itself but I'm not sure if this would work since an organization has many beneficials. Adding a column like `fullname` is not something I want to do it here

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group by` first and last names, then filter for duplicates

```sql
SELECT firstname, lastname 
FROM beneficials
GROUP BY  firstname, lastname 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

After your edits, it seems you want to select the records of people of a given organization that also appear in a different organization

```sql
SELECT *
FROM beneficials a
WHERE a.organization_id != 1
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM beneficials b
    WHERE a.firstname = b.firstname
     AND a.lastname = b.lastname
     AND b.organization_id = 1
    );
```

Comment: not quite what I need, I'm gonna edit the question soon to be more clear but what I want is something like: if the beneficial first and last name matches with beneficial from different organization ids, I want the organization ids, not the first and last name.

Comment: This is really cool, exactly what I needed! thanks a lot!